# Pick a video from iPhone photo library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to pick a video from iPhone photo library using UIImagePickerController so that i can upload it to the server.
I am able to pick the images using UIImagePickerController without any error/Crash, but while choosing(Not on actual clicking on choose button, but just selecting an video from the library) video my application crashes.
It just prints following lines on the console:

> setting movie path: (null)
>
> setting movie path: /Users/Mahesh/Library/Application Support/iPhone
> Simulator/6.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0006.mp4

Event the delegate method ***didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo*** does not get called, before it is called my application crashes. I'm just not being able to figure out what actually is causing the problem.

Following is my code for opening the iPhone Library :

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
//imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.movie", nil];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];


- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    
    // Compressing the image size
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    
    [editedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    // Get the new image from the context
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // End the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    NSData *data =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage,0.2);//PNGRepresentation(imgView.image);
   
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
    
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Please help me.. Thanks!

Comment: I am having a same issue on iOS 6.1 but code still working well on iOS7.

Comment: Are you using siulator or actual device? I think your code will work on device but it will crash on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good.

Did you set up delegate in header file?

I can only suggest 2 things:

1. Try declaring imagePicker as property.

2.When you check if it's image or video, replace

```
[mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]
```

with

```
[mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]
```

and leave video for else statement.

You will need to import `<MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>` for this check.
Hope this helps.

**Edit**: You can also try to add `imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;`

Comment: I have set up the delegate in the header file. Also i have imported <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>, But the issue still exists :(